# Call form submit action from php function on same page doesnt work

Tags: php, html

I have made an email sender but it doesn't work. I think function isn't even called.
How it's possible to do this? I don't want form to redirect on the other page.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mail Sender by midas</title>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
    </head>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submitfunc'])) {
        submitfunc();
    }
    else
    //show form
    ?>
    <body>
        <form action="?submitfunc" method="post">
            <p>
                Wyślij jako:<br />
                <input name="nadawca" type="text" /><br />
                <br />
                Odbiorca:<br />
                <input name="odbiorca" type="text" /><br />
                <br />
                Temat:<br />
                <input name="temat" type="text" /><br />
                <br />
                Wiadomość lub kod HTML:<br />
                <textarea name="wiadomosc" style="width: 210px; height: 76px;"></textarea></p>
                <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Wyślij" /></p>
            <p>
                <strong>Autor tej strony nie odpowiada za wiadomości wysłane za pośrednictwem tego skryptu.</strong></p>
        </form>
    </body>

    <?php
        function submitfunc() {
            if(isset($_POST['nadawca']) and isset($_POST['odbiorca']) and isset($_POST['wiadomosc']) and isset($_POST['temat'])) {
                $to      = $_POST['odbiorca'];
                $subject = $_POST['temat'];
                $message = $_POST['wiadomosc'];
                $headers = 'From: ' . $_POST['nadawca'] . "\r\n" .
                    'Reply-To: ' . $_POST['nadawca'] . "\r\n" .
                    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

                // postawienie @ wylaczy wyswietlanie bledow przez to wyrazenie
                $mail_sent = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, '-f ' . $_POST['nadawca']);

                echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
            }
            else{
                echo "fail";
            }
        }
    ?>
</html>
```

Comment: Your form action is `?submitfunc` in the query string which implies `$_GET['submitfunc']` but you are testing for `$_POST['submitfunc']`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1>Change the value of the action attribute of form tag as "action?submitfunc"

2>and check through get value

As follows :

```
if(isset($_GET['action'])=='submitfunc') {
    submitfunc();
}else
//show form
?>
<body>
    <form action="?action=submitfunc" method="post">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {...

    <form action="" method="post">
...

    <input type="submit" value="Wyślij" name="submit"/></p>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In your form use

```
<input type="hidden" name="submitfunc" value="1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no element with a name

> submitfunc

Please try this

```
if(isset($_POST['nadawca'])) {
  submitfunc();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you want call the function when submitting.

try this

```
   <form action="" method="post">
        <p>
            Wyślij jako:<br />
            <input name="nadawca" type="text" /><br />
            <br />
            Odbiorca:<br />
            <input name="odbiorca" type="text" /><br />
            <br />
            Temat:<br />
            <input name="temat" type="text" /><br />
            <br />
            Wiadomość lub kod HTML:<br />
            <textarea name="wiadomosc" style="width: 210px; height: 76px;"></textarea></p>
            <p>
            <input type="submit"  value="Wyślij" /></p>
        <p>
            <strong>Autor tej strony nie odpowiada za wiadomości wysłane za pośrednictwem tego skryptu.</strong></p>
    </form>
```

and also you dont have to use this function.

try this

```
        if(isset($_POST['nadawca']) and isset($_POST['odbiorca']) and isset($_POST['wiadomosc']) and isset($_POST['temat'])) {
            $to      = $_POST['odbiorca'];
            $subject = $_POST['temat'];
            $message = $_POST['wiadomosc'];
            $headers = 'From: ' . $_POST['nadawca'] . "\r\n" .
                'Reply-To: ' . $_POST['nadawca'] . "\r\n" .
                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

            // postawienie @ wylaczy wyswietlanie bledow przez to wyrazenie
            $mail_sent = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, '-f ' . $_POST['nadawca']);

            echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
        }
        else{
            echo "fail";
        }
```